# log rotate, why creating a fresh log is called log rotate instead of log delete or log refresh

Tags: logs, logrotate

Why creating a fresh log file is called log rotate instead of log refresh or log delete? What does the word rotate emphasis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called logrotate because typically it is used to "rotate" logs to new files periodically -- that is, it doesn't delete or refresh them (at least from my interpretation of those words).

One definition of "rotate" provided by the Random House Dictionary is:

> to cause to go through a cycle of changes or follow in a fixed routine of succession: to rotate crops.

`logrotate` does as described -- typically `log` becomes `log.1`, `log.1` becomes `log.2`, etc. They are not typically deleted before they reach the threshold -- log deletion is not the primary function of logrotate, rotation is.